# Центрирование блока

Tags: html, css

Серый блок и оранжевый фиксированный на странице. Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы зелёный блок стоял всегда по середине между левой частью экрана и оранжевым блоком(ширина каждого блока фиксированная). Подкиньте идею, пример, пожалуйста. Спасибо.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Альтернативный вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/_FLK/EASXu/) (без отрицательных margin и произвольной шириной центрального блока.)

Answer (score 0):

Ну, если размеры блоков вам известны, т.е. вручную заданы в пикселях, то [можно таким образом](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/eMJY5/4/). Если не руками, то все вычисления можно сделать с помощью JS/jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Фиксированность серого и оранжевого блока стоит воспринимать буквально, как в ответах выше?
Если нет, то на всякий случай: http://blog.html.it/layoutgala/LayoutGala23.html